# Define FK names in many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I what have many-to-many relationship between two entities. Everything works fine. Is there a way to define names of FKs in intermediate table(StoresPushNotifications)?

The reason to ask is that mysql do not allow to define long constraint names. It generates random FK in case. It breaks migration when I try to set migration to an earlier step.

```
[Table("Stores")]
public class StoreEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PushNotificationEntity> PushNotifications { get; set; }
}


[Table("PushNotifications")]
public class PushNotificationEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<StoreEntity> Stores { get; set; }
}
```

In my Context file,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreEntity>()
    .HasMany<PushNotificationEntity>(s => s.PushNotifications)
    .WithMany(c => c.Stores)                
    .Map(cs =>
    {
        cs.MapLeftKey("StoreId");
        cs.MapRightKey("PushNotificationId");
        cs.ToTable("StoresPushNotifications");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was actually related to the migration key lengthrather than the foreign keys.

I resolved by modifying the migration configuration method to:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CCDatabase.CCDbContext>

public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations";

    SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());

    SetHistoryContextFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
}
```

and then adding this method to limit the key lengths

```
public class MySqlHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{

    public MySqlHistoryContext(DbConnection connection, string defaultSchema) : base(connection, defaultSchema)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes Peter, the problem you mentioned is also there. But here it was FK length. In this case when I fall back to earlier migration version, EF could not find the FK in the intermediate table in the DB. The reason is that the FK's name in the DB is different from the one EF looking for.

If I change "PushNotifications" table name to something like "PN", Problem is gone.

Comment: and Peter for your problem, Follow this, this solution is straightforward. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27082231/443389. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, the solution I used was two above the one linked here - I think your suggestion looks better.